# How to find only the exact pattern matches in java?

Tags: java, regex, string, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

String "description" has both 5digit, 7digit substrings.  I would like match 5digit, 7digit with 5digit, 7digit respectively only.   But, 5digit substring extracts the whole 5 digit string and first 5 digit of 7 digits.

```
Pattern 5digitPattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{5})");
Pattern 7digitPattern = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{7})");

Matcher 5digitMatcher = 5digitPattern.matcher(description);
Matcher 7digitMatcher = 7digitPattern.matcher(description);

            if (5digitMatcher.find()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5digitMatcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                    System.out.print("\t" + 5digitMatcher.group(i));
                }
            }

            if (7digitMatcher.find()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 7digitMatcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                    System.out.print("\t" + 7digitMatcher.group(i));
                }
            }
```

Please help me in matching 5digit, 7digit with 5digit, 7digit, respectively.

Comment: I am not sure what is input and expected result, especially `7digit with 5digit`. Could you include one or more examples it in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use word boundary:

```
Pattern 5digitPattern = Pattern.compile("\\b([0-9]{5})\\b");
Pattern 7digitPattern = Pattern.compile("\\b([0-9]{7})\\b");
```

According to comment, if you want to match  digits in `abc12345def`, use negative lookaround:

```
Pattern 5digitPattern = Pattern.compile("(?<![0-9])([0-9]{5})(?![0-9])");
Pattern 7digitPattern = Pattern.compile("(?<![0-9])([0-9]{7})(?![0-9])");
```

Comment: You can't use word boundaries here because then `5digitPattern` will not match `12345` in `abc12345def` which is definitely 5 digits.

Comment: @Sweeper: fixed.

Comment: user submits description in a text box without any user input restrictions.  A few observations as follows: a) ids1.123452.54321... b) ids are12345 54321...c)ids are 12345\n54321...d)ids are 12345\t12345... please guide me!